# Can javascript methods of a aspx page can be included in another aspx

Tags: c#, javascript

javascript methods of a aspx page

```
      function Somefunction(){
      $.ajax({
                  async: false,
                  type: 'GET',
                  data: { "UserID": userID },
                  url: 'SomeHelperCode.ashx?Surveys=' + "",
                  success: display   
            });
       }
```

aspx page can be included in another aspx?

SomeHelperCode.ashx:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
  if(context.Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("Surveys")){ 
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
   string serialized; 
   //..... serialize an object..... 
   context.Response.ContentType = "text/html"; 
   context.Response.Write(serialized); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Why not put these in a `.js` file and include them in the pages you want?

Comment: Am really struggling to work out what this question is. Can you clarify / rewrite?

Comment: Sorry about the incomplete information: Using SO first time.
My question is if 'anotherDisplay' is in another aspx page how can we include that in above given javascript/aspx file?

Comment: SomeHelperCode.ashx:
  
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

    if(context.Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("Surveys")){      
    
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string serialized;
    ..... serialize an object.....

     context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
     context.Response.Write(serialized);
    }       
}

Comment: anotherCSharp.aspx is another aspx page which contains 'anotherDisplay' javascript method.

Comment: Multiline code really doesn't belong in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Keep your javascript methods in a .JS file. Then reference the JS file in your ASPX

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myJSFile.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am not able to edit the html elements present in another aspx page. How can I get the ID's of those elements in .js file

Comment: Is there any way I can give u the whole question.... I am trying to post the whole question.. but SO is giving error

Comment: Thanks Bruce, I will try it.. Then the other thing will be.. Can java script function(in the mentioned .js file) be able to forward the control to another aspx file without using C# code in the calling aspx.